# Angular material paginator not working as intended

Tags: angular, angular-material, paginator

Happy new year

I am learning angular and I used angular material paginator on my table which gets data from an API. It displays the number of rows and entries correctly on bottom, but all the data is still displayed in single page. I have searched and tried a lot of solutions on the internet but in vain.

I am using a view password component which is displayed in router-outlet.

**Component HTML**

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="passwords">

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="S.No">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> S.No. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let password"> {{password.website}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Website">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Website </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let password"> {{password.website}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="URL">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> URL </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let password"> {{password.url}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Password">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Password </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let password"> {{password.password}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>

  <mat-paginator showFirstLastButtons [pageSize]="5" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 50]">
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

**Component ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatTableDataSourcePaginator } from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatPaginator} from '@angular/material/paginator';

@Component({
    selector: 'view-passwords',
    templateUrl: './view-passwords.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./view-passwords.component.css']
})
export class ViewPasswordsComponent{

    url:any= 'http://localhost:8080/showPass';

    passwords:any;

    displayedColumns: string[] = ['S.No', 'Website', 'URL', 'Password'];
    dataSource: any;

    @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static:false}) paginator !: MatPaginator;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef){
      this.http.get(this.url)
        .subscribe(Response=>{
          (this.passwords=Response);
          this.cdr.detectChanges();
          this.dataSource= new MatTableDataSource(this.passwords);
          this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
          //console.log(this.dataSource.paginator)
        })
    }
```

**My localhost**
[my webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sMVD.png)

The bottom paginator is working fine as I can see, but the table displays all data in single page, despite the paginator showing 1-5.
Am I doing anything wrong?

Angular material paginator displaying data in multiple pages, but it displays all data in single page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored and simplified your typescript-code a bit. I think one main-problem was that you pass `passwords` instead of `dataSource` to the HTML. Can you try if the following code works?

**Component TS**:

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator)
paginator!: MatPaginator;

url = 'http://localhost:8080/showPass';

displayedColumns: string[] = ['S.No', 'Website', 'URL', 'Password'];
dataSource!: MatTableDataSource<User>;

constructor(private http: HttpClient){
    this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(res=>{
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(res);
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    })
}
```

Modification needed in **Component HTML**:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was stuck on this for 3 days. It is working now.
Can you explain why passing passwords instead of datasource was causing the issue, so that I may better understand and prevent such use in future.

Comment: `mat-table` always expects a `MatTableDataSource`-object as source. That's why you need to create a new `MatTableDataSource`-object and pass the array with the passwords via constructor of `MatTableDataSource` => `new MatTableDataSource(yourArray)`. I think `MatTableDataSource` is basically a wrapper-object where you add all the 'ingredients' for assembling the table, including the paginator configuration. Maybe you noticed that I also pass the paginator configuration to the `MatTableDataSource`- object, when I write `this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;`.